# IOS Swift how can I include the search function inside another function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar

I have 2 Controllers and one is a SubView. The **MainController** has access to the SearchBar property and the **SubViewController** does not . There is a SearchBar function in the Main Controller that I would like to invoke in the SubView Controller it is this function

```
      // MainController
      func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        // Stop doing the search stuff
        // and clear the text in the search bar
        searchBar.text = ""
        // Hide the cancel button
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        Popup.Close_View()
      }
```

What I am trying to do is wrap that function above in another function like this

```
  func Selected_Location() {
        searchBarCancelButtonClicked(SearchBar)
    }
```

so that in my SubView Controller I can do

```
// SubView Controller
   let Select_Close = MainController()

   Select_Close.Selected_Location()
```

I am new to Swift and as stated before how can I get the **searchBarCancelButtonClicked** function and call it inside another function with ? I have tried doing it in several ways such as

```
  func Selected_Location() {
        searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    }

    func Selected_Location() {
        searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar)
    }
```

Again my SubView Controller does not have access to a UISearchBar so I am trying to call the SearchBar close function from within the SubView.

Comment: With your current description there are a few things that are unclear: I am assuming MainController is the SearchBar delegate correct? You say you have two controllers and one is a subview. Do you mean you have two views, and two view controllers, where one view is a subview of the other, but they both have their own controller? Please provide more details. You will want to implement this functionality through the delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Subview, keep weak reference of MainViewController, and then call one method of mainviewcontroller `searchBarCancel`

```
class MainViewController:UIViewController {
    var subViewController: SubViewController
    func searchBarCancel(){
        searchBarCancelButtonClicked(self.searchBar)
    }
    func func2(){
        subViewController.mainController = self
    }
}

class SubViewController:UIView {
    weak var mainController: MainViewController?
    func Selected_Location() {
        mainController!.searchBarCancel()
    }
}
```